# Proper term for a callback acceptor

Tags: javascript, terminology

This is a terminology question. Function `C` that is passed to another function `F` in order to be called at some time later is named a *callback*. Is there a short generic term for `F` in this situation? "Higher-order function" or "functional" are too broad (a HOF doesn't necessarily *call* its argument).

```
 $.each(function() { zzz });
```

If we say `function() { zzz }` is a callback, how to name `$.each`?

Comment: How about _"caller"_? It's calling the callback, which is the _"caller's " "callee"_. (There is no _"official"_ term that I know of...)

Comment: With functions being first class primitives I don't think there is a name for methods that accept them. It would be like having a special name for methods that accept numbers or strings.

Comment: @JasonSperske: the term for functions accepting functions is "higher order functions". My question is rather how to call an HOF which not only accepts (and probably manipulates) its functional argument, but also calls it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a short generic term for F in this situation?

I don't think so, I don't think there's a short generic term for F that *specifically* means it accepts  a callback. From the callback's perspective, it's the "caller" or perhaps "source," but...